# How do I know a page is really fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, python, webview, webkit, web-crawler

I am using python webkit.WebView and gtk to crawl a web page. However, the web page is kind of dynamically loaded by javascript.

The WebView "load-finished" event is not sufficient to handle this. Is there any indicator/event to let me know that the page is really fully loaded even the content produced by javascript?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real way to determine if that page is fully loaded.

One method is to determine the amount of time since the last request.  However, some pages will make repeated requests continually.  This is common with tracking scripts and some ad scripts.

What I would do is use a set amount of time after the web view has said it finished loading... 5 seconds or so.  It isn't perfect, but is the best you got, as there is no way to determine what "fully loaded" is for an arbitrary page.